# count rows and echo the result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to do a row count, I want to count a row (nummer) and if there is more then 1 row with the same number then echo. but no matter how many rows I have in my tabel, it only returs 0

```
      $nummer = $_GET['nummer'];       

      $pdo = Database::connect();
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    

      $result = $pdo->prepare("select count(*) from rum where nummer=:n");
      $result->bindParam(':n', $nummer, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $result->execute();

      $rows = $result->fetchAll;
    if(count($rows) >1) {
    echo "1";}
    else {
    echo "0";
      }
```

Comment: you're using `$rows = $result->fetchAll;` missing the brackets: `$rows = $result->fetchAll();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're having two mistakes.

First one: If you're querying for `COUNT(*)` - you are getting a number of rows. For example: You're return will be a field named `COUNT(*)` with one row containing the number of rows found.

If you replace

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("select count(*) from rum where nummer=:n");
```

with

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("select * from rum where nummer=:n");
```

Second one:
Replace

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll;
```

With

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
```

`fetchAll()` is no property but a method.

The other way would be your query but naming the field (**MySQL `AS` keyword**) and calling `$rows = $result->fetch();` afterwards and checking `$rows->fieldName` for the number of found rows.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("select count(*) from rum where nummer=:n");
```

will always return one row with the count number, so doing

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll;
```

will always return one.

You may do as

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("select count(*)  as tot from rum where nummer=:n");
....
....
$rows = $result->fetchAll(); 
if($rows["tot"] > 0 ){
  echo 'something'
}else{
  echo 'something else'
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am sorry I cant give a vote up, I need more reputation

Answer (score 1):

just use `fetch()` instead of `fetchAll()`

```
$rows = $result->fetch();
if($rows[0]) >1) {
   echo "1";
} else {
   echo "0";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am sorry I cant give a vote up, I need more reputation

Answer (score 0):

Use [`PDOStatement::fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php). It is useful for *"one-column" resultsets* (which relatively often produced by queries like `SELECT COUNT(...) FROM ...`). Example:

```
$nummer = isset($_GET['nummer']) ? $_GET['nummer'] : null;

$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rum WHERE (nummer = :n)');
$stmt->bindParam(':n', $nummer, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

echo $rows > 1 ? "1" : "0";
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am sorry I cant give a vote up, I need more reputation